# Hand painted textures as shadows

Tags: shadows, toon-shading, npr

I do a lot of work with Cycles and hand-drawn textures but I want to use image textures as real shadows, so this may partially be a shader question or even compositing.

I'm inspired by Hewa's work
https://twitter.com/SueSuemejack
[image]

[image]

One solution via Shader is to cast a shadow that's a specific color. Unfortunately (even though everything is UV'd) a texture doesn't seem to work.
Yes, there are mapping & texture coordinates in my shader :

[image]

Comment: So do you want a different texture/image to show in the shadow?

Comment: @Akshay2005 yes, I'd like that. but the ability to control the shadows so they seem almost flat. Some of the textures seem projected. 
Thanks
Looking for good NPR shaders in general.

Comment: Do you have reference? I know that you told about this artist. But please provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what you want. Maybe more examples of the flat look you are talking about.

Comment: @Ashkay2005, in the new img you can see the shadows from the trees fall and the person quite differently... same in the previous image. it's not like light / it's like paint.
Thanks

Comment: One solution via Shader is to cast a shadow that's a specific color. Unfortunately (even though everything is UV'd) a texture doesn't seem to work. 
Yes there are mapping & texture coordinates in my shader...

Another solution is to manually slice the geometry where the shadows are and replace it with a new Material... Though this is a lot of work